# phantomjs on the beaglebone black and angstrom

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to fill out forms on grub hub using a beaglebone black (style B) board, loaded with angstrom. 
I tried downloading both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of phantomjs onto the board. 
This is what happens:

```
root@beaglebone:~# phantomjs 
-sh: /usr/bin/phantomjs: cannot execute binary file
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: And finally, for anyone who may mention this, the download builds its own static executable that I already copied into /usr/bin that is already in my PATH.

Comment: Where did you get the executables? Have you tried compiling phantomjs for the beaglebone black?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues. npm installing it seems to be grabbing a binary not meant for the arm processor. Following the build instructions from here:

Update: Actually I had a lot of issues getting the phatomjs build system to use the right compiler. I found it easier to just use the binaries from the Rasbery Pi distribution, they seem to work just fine on the beagle bone black.

https://github.com/aeberhardo/phantomjs-linux-armv6l

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget https://github.com/aeberhardo/phantomjs-linux-armv6l/archive/master.zip
$ unzip master.zip
$ cd phantomjs-linux-armv6l-master
$ bunzip2 *.bz2 && tar xf *.tar
```

The build Instructions can be found in the same place if you are purest.
https://github.com/aeberhardo/phantomjs-linux-armv6l
(raspberry pi build instructions)

```
Build Process

PhantomJS has been built using the process described below.

1. According to http://phantomjs.org/build.html :

$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential chrpath git-core libssl-dev libfontconfig1-dev
$ git clone git://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
$ cd phantomjs
$ git checkout 1.9

2. Download additional 3rdparty files:

$ mkdir src/qt/src/3rdparty/pixman && pushd src/qt/src/3rdparty/pixman && curl -O http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/raw/4.8/src/3rdparty/pixman/README && curl -O http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/raw/4.8/src/3rdparty/pixman/pixman-arm-neon-asm.h && curl -O http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/raw/4.8/src/3rdparty/pixman/pixman-arm-neon-asm.S; popd

3. Open ./build.sh and delete lines 11-34:

.. ...
11 if [[ "$MAKEFLAGS" != "" ]]; then
12 MAKEFLAGS_JOBS=$(echo $MAKEFLAGS | egrep -o '\-j[0-9]+' | egrep -o '[0-9]+')
.. ...
34 fi
.. ...

4. Open ./src/qt/preconfig.sh and add the option ' -no-pch' to QT_CFG after ' -no-stl':

.. ...
29 QT_CFG+=' -no-exceptions'       # Don't use C++ exception
30 QT_CFG+=' -no-stl'              # No need for STL compatibility
31 QT_CFG+=' -no-pch'
.. ...

5. Start compilation:

$ nohup ./build.sh --confirm > build.sh.out 2> build.sh.err &
6. Create tarball according to http://phantomjs.org/build.html :

./deploy/package.sh
7. The tarball can be found in the ./deploy directory.
```

Seems to be the solution. Although it is a bit weird opening and editing the build files, and I don't have a good feel for why that is needed. Also be advised it take over 30 minutes to build.